# Regex segmentation fault

Tags: c++, regex, debian-stretch

I have a regex that fires `segmentation fault` error. 
After some tests I noticed that `[\s\S]*\s+` part of regex is making problems if string is larger than 15 KB, so sometimes it works but sometimes it crashes.

Here is the C++ code compiled with g++ (gcc v. 6.3.0)

```
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::regex regex(
            R"([\s\S]*\s+)",
            std::regex_constants::icase
    );

    std::ifstream ifs("/home/input.txt");
    const std::string input(
            (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
            (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>())
            );

    std::cout << "input size: " << input.size() << std::endl;

    bool reg_match = std::regex_match(input, regex);

    std::cout << "matched: " << reg_match << std::endl;

}
```

What is going on, why is it happening with such pattern and why is it affected by input size?

**UPDATE:**

Error produced by running binary when compiled with -fsanitize=address:

> g++ -std=c++11 /home/app/src/test.cpp -o /home/app/bin/test -fsanitize=address

```
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==37041==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffbff8edff8 (pc 0x55afae25781b bp 0x7ffbff8ee010 sp 0x7ffbff8edff0 T0)
    #0 0x55afae25781a in bool __gnu_cxx::operator==<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&) (/home/app/bin/test+0x1981a)
    #1 0x55afae2587bd in std::__detail::_Executor<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::__cxx11::regex_traits<char>, true>::_M_dfs(std::__detail::_Executor<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::__cxx11::regex_traits<char>, true>::_Match_mode, long) (/home/app/bin/test+0x1a7bd)
    #2 0x55afae25e2d2 in std::__detail::_Executor<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::__cxx11::regex_traits<char>, true>::_M_rep_once_more(std::__detail::_Executor<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::__cxx11::regex_traits<char>, true>::_Match_mode, long) (/home/app/bin/test+0x202d2)
.
.
.
 #251 0x55afae25e2d2 in std::__detail::_Executor<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::__cxx11::regex_traits<char>, true>::_M_rep_once_more(std::__detail::_Executor<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::__cxx11::regex_traits<char>, true>::_Match_mode, long) (/home/app/bin/test+0x202d2)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow (/home/app/bin/test) in std::__detail::_Executor<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std:__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*,std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::__cxx11::regex_traits<char>, true>::_M_dfs(std::__detail::_Executo<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::submatch<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::__cxx11::regex_trats<char>, true>::_Match_mode, long)
    ==37017==ABORTING
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194027/discussion-on-question-by-boy-regex-segmentation-fault).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a full answer but for some reason there is a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) happening while matching your regular expression. This is usually caused either by too much data on the stack or by too many levels of recursion. Looking at your program I don't see any large objects on the stack (the string object on the stack is small since it's data is on the heap). However, the state machines used for regex parsing are known for making many recursive function calls (this goes together with your long Address Sanitizer output). You have a couple of options (I would try them in this order):

- Ensure you are compiling with an appropriate level of optimization. At higher levels of optimization compilers often push less frames on the stack (see "[tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)").
- Try passing [`std::regex_constants::optimize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) to encourage the regex code to take more time for optimizing while constructing the state machine for regex processing.
- Rethink your regex. Maybe you can simplify it in a way that results in a simpler state machine working with less levels of recursion? The `[\s\S]*` part looks a little unconventional.
- Modify your program to process input data in smaller chunks, e.g. line by line.
- Increase your stack size. On POSIX systems you can do so by calling `ulimit -s <stack size in kB>` before you run your program.
- Consider compiling your program with [automatically growing stacks (`-fsplit-stacks`)](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks). Note that this comes at the cost of some performance.